# How to get file extension and path from V2 Box iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, box-api

I'm trying to retrieve the metadata from my box account via the IOS API V2 from BOX.

Digging into the API It looks like there is no field for the "file extension" and the "full path":

```
- (id)initWithQueryStringParameters:(NSDictionary *)queryStringParameters
{
    self = [super initWithQueryStringParameters:queryStringParameters];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        _name = nil;
        _description = nil;
        _contentCreatedAt = nil;
        _contentModifiedAt = nil;
        _parentID = nil;
        _sharedLink = nil;
    }

return self;
```

}

Please correct me if I'm wrong (and maybe show me where in the API these metadata are listed, thanks !)

If I'm not wrong...probably initWithQueryStringParameters should have in the future two extra fields (_fileExtension and _path) and this could be considered a RFE.

I would not consider this lack of additional metadata too much of a big deal (will make a 2 liners to extract the extension and some hack to put together the path components) but would be nice to have them.. .

Thanks,
       dom

Comment: isn't the extension just the end of the name?

Comment: yes it is, so it's not a big deal if there is no explicit key for it in the BOX API, but other APIs have this information and seems quite standard to provide them.

Comment: I am an engineer for something that would be considered a competitor... we only have one field and it is the entire absolute path.

Comment: Yes, the absolute path is what would be nice to have  in the box api. If you also have the extension of the file as metadata field then I know where you work ;-)

Comment: nope... we don't have a public API.

Comment: oh well, just guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full path in the raw Box API is called the path_collection, and it's an optional field you can request via a ?fields= parameter on the API call.